# load JPanel that contains another JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, containers

I'm trying to load a Class that extends JPanel and has components from another Class that also extends JPanel into another Class.
[image]

And this is what i need to achieve: 
[image]

Example of `First.java`

```
  public class First extends JPanel{
      JPanel cont = new JPanel();
          public First(){
          cont.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
          }
       }
```

Example of `Second.java`

```
  public class Second extends JPanel{
      JPanel cont = new JPanel();
      First first_panel = new First();
          public Second(){
          cont.setBackground(Color.RED);
          cont.add(first_panel);
          }
      }
```

Example of `Container.java`

```
   public class Container extends JFrame{
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       JPanel cont = new JPanel();
       Second second_panel = new Second();
          public Container(){
          cont.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
          cont.add(second_panel);
          frame.add(cont);
          frame.setVisible(true);
          }
      }
```

I'm able to load one by one classes but when i'm trying to load panel that contains another **panel.class** the GUI doesn't show it. What is wrong with the logic ? What's the problem?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two basic problems in the code shown.

1. Each class both extended and had an instance of the component it dealt with.
2. Neither panel had any content that would have given it a non-zero size, nor overrode the `getPreferredSize` method, so they were 0x0 px.

See the effect of this MCVE.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Container {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel cont = new JPanel();
    Second second_panel = new Second();

    public Container() {
        cont.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        cont.add(second_panel.getPanel());
        frame.add(cont);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Container();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class Second {

    JPanel cont = new JPanel();
    First first_panel = new First();

    public Second() {
        cont.setBackground(Color.RED);
        cont.add(new JLabel("Second"));
        cont.add(first_panel.getPanel());
    }

    public JComponent getPanel() {
        return cont;
    }
}

class First {

    JPanel cont = new JPanel();

    public First() {
        cont.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        cont.add(new JLabel("First"));
    }

    public JComponent getPanel() {
        return cont;
    }
}
```